# Role-based sharing rules for partner community users

Tags: sharing, partner-communities, role-hierarchy, sharing-rule

When dealing with role-based record sharing in a Private sharing model, I often run into a scenario where managers should see their peers' records while their subordinates should not.  It's simple enough to create a sharing rule that allows users within a particular role in the hierarchy to have access to each others' records.

However, this can't easily be replicated with a Partner Community.  I have a scenario where I am using a Private sharing model and 3 roles for each partner account: Executive, Manager, and User.  These roles are generated individually each time I enable an account as partner.  For example, when Account A is enabled as a partner, it creates three roles: Account A Executive, Account A Manager, and Account A User.  When I do the same for Account B, it generates three completely separate roles, which makes sense in terms of restricting access between partners' records.  But if I would like to, for each partner account, extend sharing between that account's Executive users, I am stuck.

It appears to me that the only non-programmatic way to achieve this is to create a separate sharing rule for every partner account.  This would only work on a very small scale.  Does anyone have any scalable solutions to this?  I know that this can be achieved through Apex-based sharing, but I would like to find a simpler solution if possible.

Comment: I have been hitting a similar issue with Customer Community Plus users though that is with custom objects. I really suspect that there is not really any solution other than using Apex Based sharing for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Super User access:

> **Super User Access**
>
> Users can be assigned super user access to give them access to data
>   ***owned*** by other users belonging to the ***same role*** or those below in the
>   hierarchy. For example, a Partner Manager with super user access can
>   see data owned by other users in the Partner Manager role and the
>   Partner User roles.

[Documentation Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=partner_portal_partner_users.htm&type=0)

When a user has this access they can see data by their peers (same role) and those below them but **NOT** roles above them.

**In order to set this up for a Partner Community:**

*Go to Communities Settings*

- Select the checkbox "Enable Partner Super User Access"
- Save.

*Then on the Partner User's contact record:*

- Press the "Manage External User" button
- Select "Enable Super User Access".  (If this option does not appear, it needs to be added to the Contact's page layout first)

Comment: This is a great candidate for Super User Access! Provides simple horizontal access within a Community, at a user level without the creation of Sharing Rules.

Comment: This is applicable only for partner portals right? not for Communities. Because in communities, I don't see any checkbox for `Enable Partner Super User Access`

Comment: @javanoob - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customer_super_user_access.htm

Comment: In addition to Eric's answer You can also add Super User Access permission by app settings in permission sets.